# Manage Deployment of Database Changes in Magento

Tags: database, git, magento, github, magento-1.7

I have three instances of my Magento site:-

1. Local
2. Test on Web Server
3. Live on Web Server

I can manage my files/folder and code changes through `Git`, But how do I manage my Database changes.

When I deploy for the first time, I will import the sqldump. But subsequent to that how do I update/deploy my each and every database change, primarily the:-schema changes?

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle this is by introducing DB schema changes via extensions. Each new feature or feature set that relates to a specific DB schema should be packaged together as an Extension. Add a directive in your **config.xml** and then you will be able to include a DB installation file that is related to the version of the extension and will only load once when the new extension version is detected. Here is an example:

**Make sure you got these directives in your config.xml:**

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        ...
        <resources>
             <extensionname_setup>
                  <setup>
                      <module>Namespace_Extensionname</module>
                  </setup>
             </extensionname_setup>
             ...
        </resources>
    </global>
 </config>
```

**Then add file 
/app/code/community/Namespace/Extensionname/sql/extensionname_setup/install-1.0.0.php**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Create table 
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('extensionname/entity'))
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Entity ID')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 128, array(
        ), 'Name')
    ->addColumn('description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        ), 'Description')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Creation Time')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Modified Time')
    ->setComment('Shop by Brand Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

If you have incremental changes to the same extension, you can then introduce incremental DB schema changes with files that are named to match the from version to version and update the version of the extensio accordingly. This will also only be triggered once. Example:

```
upgrade-<ver1>-<ver2>.php
```